# Python, detect key input on console without showing the input?

Tags: python, input, console, keypress

What I want to do is simple.

I have a code to detect when a key is pressed to proceed to different actions.

I made a test version of the code

```
import keyboard

print('test press a number key')

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            print('1')
            break
        if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
            print('2')
            break
    except:
        break

input()
```

And here is the result on the console.

```
test press a number key
2
2
```

It shows me the '2' of the print function, and it also show me the '2' that I input.
Basically, is there a way to make it so it doesn't show what I input on the console but just the prints?

Answer (score 2):

In python use getpass:

```
import getpass
secret_input = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter hidden input: ")
```

on non windows or unix systems you can turn off echo for regular input with:

```
import os
os.system("stty -echo")
```

and turn it back on with:

```
os.system("stty echo")
```